# suppress Name dtype from python pandas describe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, format, series

Lets say I have

```
r = pd.DataFrame({'A':1 ,
              'B':pd.Series(1,index=list(range(4)),dtype='float32')})
```

And `r['B'].describe()[['mean','std','min','max']]` gives an output :

```
mean    1.0
std     0.0
min     1.0
max     1.0
Name: B, dtype: float64
```

But from the above output , **how should I get rid or suppress the last line** " `Name:B, dtype: float64` "

I figured out one way to achieve this

```
x=r['B'].describe()[['mean','std','min','max']]
print "mean ",x['mean'],"\nstd ",x['std'],"\nmin ",x['min'],"\nmax ",x['max']
```

which gives the desired output :

```
mean  1.0 
std  0.0 
min  1.0 
max  1.0
```

Is there any cleaner to achieve this output directly from pd.describe( )

Answer (score 9):

If need output as `DataFrame` add [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
x=r['B'].describe()[['mean','std','min','max']].reset_index()
print (x)
  index    B
0  mean  1.0
1   std  0.0
2   min  1.0
3   max  1.0
```

And then use [`DataFrame.to_string`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_string.html):

```
print (x.to_string(header=None, index=None))
mean  1.0
 std  0.0
 min  1.0
 max  1.0
```

Comment: Worked perfect.

Answer (score 5):

***better answer***
use `to_csv` on dataframe

```
rd = r.B.describe()[['mean','std','min','max']].reset_index()
print(rd.to_csv(header=None, index=None, sep='\t'))

mean    1.0
std     0.0
min     1.0
max     1.0
```

***old answer***

```
for name, value in r['B'].describe()[['mean','std','min','max']].iteritems():
    print('{:<5s} {:2.1f}'.format(name, value))

mean  1.0
std   0.0
min   1.0
max   1.0
```

Comment: I was using `value_counts` rather than `describe`, so I wanted to preserve the index and remove a trailing newline:
`df.reset_index().to_csv(header=None,index=None,sep='\t')[:-1]`