# Removing time from Pandas datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

Hey all I am writing a code which takes user input and updates an excel spreadsheet using the Pandas module.  ere is a snippet of code I have

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime as dt

df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 500)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

def view_books():
    option1 = True
    while option1 == True:
        choice = input("\nWhat would you like to view?:\n1) Entire spreadsheet\n2) Upcoming events\n3) Total profit\n")
        if choice == "1":
            print("\n",df)
            option1 = False
        elif choice == "2":
            print("Upcoming events:\n")
            for i in range(len(df['Date'])):
                date = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'][i])
                today = dt.datetime.today()
                if date>today:
                    print(df.iloc[i],"\n")
                else:
                    pass
            option1 = False
        elif choice == "3":
            print("Total profit is: £",df["Profit"].sum())
            option1 = False
        elif choice != "1" or "2" or "3":
            print("\nInvalid choice\n")
```

My question is when I run this function and choose option 2, I get 2 problems:

```
Upcoming events:

Date                   2017-09-16 00:00:00
Time                              14:00:00
Event                    Man U v.s Arsenal
Bookmaker                            Coral
Bookmaker Stake                          2
Bookmaker Odds                         1.4
Exchange                          Smarkets
Exchange Stake                           3
Exchange Liability                       5
Exchange Odds                            2
Profit                                  40
Name: 1, dtype: object
```

How do I get rid of both the `00:00:00` and the `Name: 1, dtype object?`

Any and all help appreciated!

Comment: In the `pd.to_datetime...` pass the option `format=“%Y-%m-%d”, ` to remove the `00:00:00`

Comment: In addition use reset.index() if you need only the dataframe,(See the following)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40278845/suppress-name-dtype-from-python-pandas-describe]

Comment: I've tried passing format as a parameter, and checking the Pandas documentation to see if I've done anything wrong but it still doesn't seem to be changing. Any ideas?

Comment: What about rewriting the Date column i.e. `df['Date']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date'][i],format=“%Y-%m-%d”, )`. Something like that

Comment: That's exactly what I did, as per the documentation with no luck :(